# Lazy load content on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, lazy-loading

I am looping trough my results in a twig view within Symfony project..

```
<ul class="timeline">
     {% for item in items %}
         <li>
            {{ item.name }}
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As I have many results I want to display just 10, and than on scroll to dynamically add 10 more, and 10 again..

Is there any library for lazy load content like this or just a plain JS code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to dynamically load content when scrolling using only Js.You can use this for things like

> 1. Lazy-loading of images or other content as a page is scrolled.
> 2. Implementing "infinite scrolling" web sites, where more and more
>    content is loaded and rendered as you scroll, so that the user
>    doesn't have to flip through pages.
> 3. Reporting of visibility of advertisements in order to calculate ad
>    revenues. Deciding whether or not to perform tasks or animation
>    processes based on whether or not the user will see the result.